# Can I re-aerate in the Primary?

Tags: yeast, primary, aeration

Is there a downside to shaking the primary fermenter to re-suspend the yeast if the fermentation is going slowly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The downside would be potential oxygenation of the beer, but "rousing" of yeast is a long-established practice. I'd suggest gentle swirling rather than shaking.

Comment: Gentle swirling is the key.